# Rails create has_many association models from a list of options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have options for timeslots that a user should be able to choose from:

```
[
  { day_of_week: 'Thursday', time_of_day: '7 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Thursday', time_of_day: '8 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Thursday', time_of_day: '9 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Friday', time_of_day: '7 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Friday', time_of_day: '8 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Friday', time_of_day: '9 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Friday', time_of_day: '10 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Saturday', time_of_day: '8 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Saturday', time_of_day: '9 am' },
  { day_of_week: 'Saturday', time_of_day: '10 am' }
]
```

`User` has_many `:timeslots` and a user should be able to select `Timeslot` based on the list above.

My current html:

```
   <%= simple_form_for(current_user, url: registration_path(:user)) do |f| %>
        <% @timeslots.each do |day, values| %>
          <div class="lead">
            <%= day %>
          </div>
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :timeslots, values.sort_by { |slot| slot[:time_of_day].to_i } do |ff, something| %>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <%= ff.input_field :selected %>
                <%= ff.object.time_of_day %>
              </label>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <% end %>
```

I'd like to do two things:
1. Not have to prebuild timeslots in the database for a user
2. I can change the list (add or remove) and that would reflect the options available to the user to select from

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1., it is a good idea to store timeslots in the database as it sounds like you want to add and remove timeslots from users.

You can then have an admin interface (as per Requirement 2), to add and remove timeslots that a user is able to select. You do not want to hard code this. Making it a model and telling Rails all about the model relatinoships actually simplifies the problem of adding a form field for timeslots.

Assuming timeslots are a model and the model relationships are defined in your model files, you can call `f.association :timeslot` on your user. Simple form automatically generates a dropdown/combobox of available timeslots which you can select (multiple) timeslots from.

You might want to customize the label text of those timeslots, Im not sure how well Simple Form handles that out of the box.

```html
<%= simple_form_for(current_user, url: registration_path(:user)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.association :timeslots %>
        <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To give more insight, the hardcoded values are a list of all the possible values for timeslots to be created and not the ones available in the database. Given those available values, timeslots would be created in the database for that user.